# React - setInterval() behaving differently on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, setinterval

I am perplexed on an issue I am facing. I have developed a MERN app, where one component within the app is displaying data as a chart from my redux store. In order to give some semblance of "dynamic" data, I have set up a setInterval inside a useEffect hook to fetch the data and update the store every 60 seconds.

Now when I deploy the application on a on-prem server and view the app through a browser on my desktop, the functionality works as expected. Every minute a GET request is made to my backend and new data is being displayed. When this happens **ONLY** the graph component re-renders - i.e the **WHOLE** webpage does't reload.

```
// Get all alerts upon render and at regular intervals of 1 minute.
  useEffect(() => {
    let fetchInterval = setInterval(() => {
      dispatch(getAlert()) //This is the GET request
      .then(() => {
        dispatch(reset())
      })
    }, 60000)
    
    return () => clearInterval(fetchInterval)
    
  },[])
```

But when I access the exact same app through a mobile browser, every minute the **ENTIRE** web page refreshes - identical to if I had pressed the refresh button. This would be greatly annoying to the user as any selections they would have made would be wiped out.

Can anyone tell me how I can have the same functionality on the mobile browser as compared to the desktop? Also why does this happen? Is this an optimisation by mobile web browsers?

Another thing I noticed is that the data is very slow to fetch on my mobile device even if I am using the same wifi internet connection. Can this be improved?
Greatly appreciate your support!

Comment: What browser are you using on mobile?

Comment: I am using google chrome on both mobile and desktop.

Comment: everything you've told us checks out. What do you mean by the WHOLE page reloading? As in your fetch request actually reloads the page, or do you mean react re-renders the build tree? If it's the former, are you submitting a form and missing a e.preventDefault() somewhere?.. blind guessing since it's weird. If it's the latter.. maybe you need a unique key for whatever component should update after the GET request.

Comment: @sleepystar96 the former. When I do a fetch request it reloads the page, identical to if I had pressed the reload button. I am not submitting a form, and this behavior is not seen on the desktop browser version. I am also noticing that when I access the application through mobile, I do see these warn messages from NGINX "[warn] 29#29: *13 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/4/00/0000000004 while reading upstream". Maybe this is also causing an issue?

Comment: How do you know it refreshes on the GET request? Have you tried making a version of the app without the GET request to see if the refresh still triggers? Also another wild guess: I can think of some bizarre scenario where a firewall or dns server on your network could be redirecting your get request (e.g. HTTP 307) for your mobile device so you don't access that resource (only reason I think this is because your network seems to be treating your mobile device differently than your desktop), so get that checked/whitelisted for your network? But if that's the case I feel like your request fails.